# 'Function components cannot be given refs.' while using react-native-gesture-handler with react-native-reanimated

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I am warping a gesture handler from `react-native-gesture-handler` with animated flatlist from `react-native-reanimated`

```js
import Animated from "react-native-reanimated"
import { NativeViewGestureHandler } from "react-native-gesture-handler"

...

 <NativeViewGestureHandler>
              <Animated.FlatList
                 ...
              />
  </NativeViewGestureHandler>
```

And this error pops.

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `NativeViewGestureHandler`.
```

How could I solve this issue?

**Edit:**
When I change the `Animated.FlatList` to FlatList from `react-native` / `react-native-gesture-handler`, it works fine. And I'm not using `ref` on this screen at all.

I also tried to update to lastest version (2.5.0) of `react-native-gesture-handler`. Exactly the same error as above mentioned.

Dependencies version:

```json
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
```

Comment: Currently I leave the error there since I'm not using the ref. You are welcome to update here if there are any changes.